# How can I achieve database sharding for my MYSQL database with Django

Tags: mysql, django, database-design, nosql, distributed-system

I am trying to understand the concept of system design and trying to practically implement it. One thing that struck my mind is how exactly do I achieve sharding of my databases in Django.

Here is what I mean :

Suppose I have multiple machines in my distributed system, all of which were previously using a centralised database to read/write data which was fine. I only had to specify it in my setting.py file in django.

Now lets say, I want to implement database sharding for my MYSQL database and shard the servers based on the username keys. Now suppose when a request comes in how exactly will Django search I mean how do I specify it where my data is stored. Is there any way to tell django that my database is sharded. And moreover suppose a request want to view the contents which is available in multiple databases how exactly will it gather the data from all the database servers . Since all my database servers now will be having different address so how do I specify in django that how it has to configure these things.

Or is there already a package in dango-python that lets me achieve this. Basically I want to know from the beginning how can I achieve sharding for my distributed system with Django.

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all Sharding solution.  And I doubt if Django has any explicit support.  A "proxy" can help with redirecting for a simple query, but not for merging data from multiple shards.  Please elaborate on your app and provide the 'math' that demonstrates the need for sharding; there may be easier alternatives.

Comment: No such need, I just want to learn the concepts by implementing it. You didn't get my point when a request is recieved by a django app server, how is it gonna query all other databases because we need to specify this in our setting.py file, whenever we are using database to which django is going to talk to. So lets say we have n database server, how are we gonna specify this in setting.py file. Lets say we did this but everytime querying all other nodes in our system for some out of context data. Won't it be too hectic for us.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:  A query comes in from one "user" for just his data.  There is a mapping *somewhere* that says that that user is on shard N.  Where?--More in a moment.

Case 2:  A query comes in to, say, average the info about all users.  So, it must access all shards.  The list of Shards is *somewhere*.  Where?...

Either way, the mapping must be dynamic because you *will* increase the number of shards someday.

Where?

Case 1:

Plan A:  Each client maintains the mapping between users and shards (many-to-one).  This might be a local file.

Plan B:  Each database has a copy of the mapping.  How it is a lookup followed by a "connect".

Plan C:  Before even getting to the API, the request is intercepted and the userID is parsed out of the request.  Then the API request goes to a particular client.  (Think of it as sharding at the client level instead of just the database.)

Plan D:  Have a Proxy (HAProxy, MySQL Router, etc) between the client and the databases.  It takes care of routing (at least for a single-db request).  This *may* be the closest to what you envisioned.

Plan E:  Use MariaDB and its "Connectors" or "FederatedX".  This will allow one db connection to reach through to other(s).  Caveat: some queries will be much slower.

Back to Case 2.  You effectively need a program that is willing and able to connect to all the shards, either simultaneously or sequentially.  If the query needs to do SUMs, COUNTs, etc, you are on your own.

See also "Spider", preferably via MariaDB (instead of MySQL).

As for the ".py".  Move your head away from this narrow focus on what Django has.  You need to think bigger, possibly not even using Django.  (Sorry, I don't know anything about Django to be more specific.)

Comment: ok that is correct I got it, but while accessing all the shards I need to tell django that what databases we will be using to get its cool ORM functionality. So lets say I have n(16) database servers(shards) does that mean I need to specify all 16 databases in my settings file of django? Won't that be too hectic or overkill. There must be some way to tell django that we are sharding the data

Comment: @EquinoxSolutions - I doubt if Django handles sharding.